# How to correctly save plot in file?

Tags: plotting, export

I am running:

```
WordCloud[{{"aw", 5}, {"bw", 1}}]
```

and I am getting correct plot in notebook, which looks like:
[image]

Now if I am trying to increase resolution with width 1200 pixels while maintaining original aspect ratio and for it modified code to:

```
WordCloud[{{"aw", 5}, {"bw", 1}}, ImageSize -> 1200, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

it produces incorrect image which looks like:

[image]

Same incorrect result if I try to save plot as `png` file with width 1200 pixels and maintain original aspect ratio. Code:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Export["sample.png",WordCloud[{{"aw",5}, {"bw", 1}}], ImageSize->1200, AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

**Question:** How to correct my code above to get plot with specifed width in pixels and maintain original aspect ratio? I do not only need only to get 1200 pixel width plot but to be able to change width value to different value and get correct image.

Comment: On my system (MM 12.3.1, Mac OS) your code produces a PNG that shows both words, regardless of size.  What version of Mathematica and OS are you using?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Strange. I use Mathematica 13.2.1.0. on Windows 10.

Comment: may be try: `Export["sample.png",WordCloud[{{"aw",5}, {"bw", 1}}]//Evaluate, ImageSize->1200, AspectRatio->Automatic]`?

Comment: @chris Result is the same, incorrect image. Does the code on your system produces correct image file? If yes, which is your OS and Mathematica system?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Updated question. It seems the problem is in notebook too when increasing width.

Comment: @chris Updated question. It seems the problem is in notebook too when increasing width.

Comment: A few comments:  `ImageSize->1200`, is in points not pixels.  I don't believe `WordCloud` is documented as supporting `AspectRatio`. If you would like a 1200 pixel image, spec that as part of `Export`.  i.e., `Export["sample.png", WordCloud[{{"aw", 5}, {"bw", 1}}], 
 RasterSize -> 1200]`

Comment: @ihojnicki That worked even with `RasterSize ->3000` . For now for me value of `3000` is enough so thank you for solving the problem. If I set value to `4000` it is does not works correctly and I think it is a bug in a program and I will add appropriate tag to my question. Also, if I select `image size` from suggestion bar it gives me this code `Show[%75, ImageSize -> {631, 386}, AspectRatio -> Full]`. Since `Show` accepts `WordCloud` ouput I thought that `AspectRatio` is also supported by `WordCloud`.